# How to find if there are javascript errors in the page using selenium rc

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC and I would like to know if there were any JavaScript errors in the page.

Is there any Selenium API to check if there are any JavaScript errors?

Comment: the only way I can see is to use `getEval` to run some javascript which would fail if there were a javascript error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's anything in the Selenium API that can do this.  How about putting something like this after all your other JavaScript:

```
document.write('<!--JSOK-->');
```

then asserting that it exists from your test script?  If the JavaScript has already thrown an error then `<!--JSOK-->` won't be rendered to the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's not Selenium, but I've found that for javascript FireBug is the best hands down imho.  I know you are going for the "all in one" tool, but I'd consider making an exception in this case.

Comment: Selenium RC is an automated web UI testing tool and serves a completely different purpose to Firebug.